# What is the most easy and fast way to edit PE executable file to make it load specified DLL at startup?

Tags: dll, load, edit, reverse-engineering, portable-executable

I need to make some exe file to load my DLL at startup...
What is the easiest way to do it?
I need this exactly, no any injectors or starters.

I though about adding one more code section into exe, rewriting to there entry point logic and placing DLL loading code, then NOPing original entry point and calling my custom made entry point function. Will this work?
Are there any other easer ways?

I also thinking about changing one of system dll name in hex editor to name of my DLL. Will this work? If my dll then load that replaced system dll?
Any thoughts?

Comment: Try researching how viruses are written as it is similar to what you are doing, although I'm sure that's not what you are doing :). Maybe append your dll to the end of the file and change the entry point of the exe?

Comment: Ehm, I guess, I need to load this DLL from memory somehow then, which is harder than loading from disk. This is crazy program activation system, which my boss think is easy to make. I must protect third party exe that I don't have sources and this exe would not be rebuilt for me. So, I want to execute custom code at it's startup to check license.

Comment: Seriously, maybe there are virus toolkits which will easily do what you are trying.

Comment: Umm I guess if I will not get any ideas here, I should search for viruses toolkits :O, but I prefer some general ideas or even better step by step guide :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding it to the PE's import table should be enough. Woodman's lists a few tools which can do it:

http://www.woodmann.com/collaborative/tools/index.php/Category:Import_Editors